# Create expandable div like facebook wall

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have similar case like facebook wall.
In place of `post` in my case user enters `URL`.

Initially it looks like this:
[image: Initial view]

I have text box for this in place of text area.

Now when user takes cursor it changes to :

[image: After cursur taken into text area]

Problem with me is how I expand textbox and show button like share in facebook when user takes cursor into textbox.

More when user increase the content into textarea it, downside div which contains button automatically move down.

In my case when user enters url , I show url preview below text box. preview size varies. So how can i create similar case show that button below it automatically move downward.

MY initial view:

[image: Initial view]

When user enter cursor into Text box it changes to:

[image]

I have manually place buttons at some distance. I want them to automatically repositioned as per preview size.

when user enters url it looks like this:

[image: after url entered]

I want to show buttons just below textbox like facebook does. When url entered as per preview size the buttons should move downward.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Buttons are css button, placed into div. Working in PHP.

Source code:

http://codetidy.com/6983/

```
<html>
   <head>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
     <link href="content/rateit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="content/bigstars.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <style>
//css for button

         label {
        color: #B90000; /* makes the text-black */
}
         label2 {
        color: #3b5999; /* makes the text-black */
}

      </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" class="cssStatics" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" class="cssButtons" type="text/css" href="css/linkPreview.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/linkPreview.js" ></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.linkPreview').linkPreview();
                // setting max number of images $('.linkPreview').linkPreview({imageQuantity: "put here the number"});
                // e.g. $('.linkPreview').linkPreview({imageQuantity: 15});
            });
        </script>

   </head>
   <body style="height: 560px">

       <div>
         <img alt="" src= "3.png" style="top: 15px; right: 689px; position: absolute; height: 91px; width: 417px"/>
      </div>
      <div >

      <div style="top: 20; left:20"> <img id="i1" src="">      </img>
       </div>


     <div class="rateit bigstars" id="rateit99"  style="z-index: 1; display:none; left: 45px; top: 45px;" data-rateit-starwidth="32" data-rateit-starheight="32">

         <label color="red" style="z-index: 1;  left: 600px; top: 180px;" onclick="alert($('#rateit99').rateit('value'))">
           <b>
             Rate Me 
           </b>
         </label>
       </div>

         <form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
       <!--     <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 40px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">           
               <label><b>Enter URL:</b></label><br/>
            </div> -->

        <div style="  width: 15%;    margin: auto;    margin-top: -10px;    text-decoration: none;    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;    padding: 10px 20px;    text-align: justify; ">
            <div class="linkPreview" style="z-index: 2;">
                <div id="previewLoading"></div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <div style="left: 420px; top: 40px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">

                    <input type="text" id="text" name="sent" contenteditable="true"  style=" text-align: left; height: 30px; width:512px; " placeholder="Enter URL ..."/></input>

                    <div id="postPreview" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="left: 420px; top: 70px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">
                <div id="preview">
                    <div id="previewImages">
                        <div id="previewImage"><img src="img/loader.gif" style="margin-left: 43%; margin-top: 39%;" ></img>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="photoNumber" value="0" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="previewContent">
                        <div id="closePreview" title="Remove" ></div>
                        <div id="previewTitle"></div>
                        <div id="previewUrl"></div>
                        <div id="previewDescription"></div>
                        <div id="hiddenDescription"></div>
                        <div id="previewButtons" >
                            <div id="previewPreviousImg" class="buttonLeftDeactive" ></div><div id="previewNextImg" class="buttonRightDeactive"  ></div>
                            <div class="photoNumbers" ></div>
                            <div class="chooseThumbnail">
                                Choose a thumbnail
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="noThumb" class="noThumbCb" />
                        <div class="nT"  >
                            <span id="noThumbDiv" >No thumbnail</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>

                <div class="previewPostedList"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div  style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 280px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('text').value)" >

    <button onclick="show2(); myfunc();" id="b1" >
      Get Sentiment 
    </button>

  </div>
  <div id="d1" height="40" width="60" name="sent2"  style=" border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:80px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" placeholder="Preview title" >
         </div>
         <div id="d2" height="40"  style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:100px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; min-width:60; overflow:auto" placeholder="Preview Url">
         </div>
         <div id="d3" height="80"  border="1" style="border:1px solid black; z-index: 1; left: 950px; top:140px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" placeholder="Preview Desciption">
         </div>
         </form>      

       <div style="z-index: 1; left: 720px; top:280px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">
   <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" >
    View Graph   
  </button>
</div>

</div>
<h4>
  <div id="txtHint" align="justify" style="z-index: 1; display:none; color:#C7F0FF; left: 35px; top: 260px; padding: 20px; position: absolute; border:1px; margin-top: 0px; width:300px;height:350px;overflow:auto; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; border-radius:7px; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(100%, #F70247), color-stop(150%, white), color-stop(100%, #D7E9F5)); background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F70247 0%, #F70247 10%, #F70247 130%); ">

  </div>

</h4>

<script src="content/jquery.rateit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to do this? It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing the code.

Comment: Can you please share some code so tht I can help you out. Not sure if this will help you completely, but I did very similar to this by maintaining two nested divs and using display:none

Comment: YEs sure Guys! but I left it because its very lengthy and long!